# How do we upgrade our vue.js/jest tests past version 24? Things break a little at v26, more at v27

Tags: vue.js, testing, jestjs

We're currently testing a vue.js app with jest 24.9.0, ts-jest 24.30, and @types/jest 24.9.1 . We see that jest is at v27 and I looked at upgrading, but things broke all over the place, so I backtracked to this combination:

@types/jest: upgrade from 24.9.1 to 26.0.14

jest: upgrade from 24.9.0 to 26.6.3

ts-jest: upgrade from 24.3.0 to 26.5.6 (shouldn't matter).

It now looks like `mount(VUE COMPONENT, { propsData: props })` is returning an empty `<body />` element (`mount` is imported from `@vue/test-utils`).

Anyone have suggestions? We also get many warning messages about `finding components with 'find' or 'get'`  -- how should we replace our querySelector strings (once we actually have sub-elements in the objects returned from `mount` so there's something to find or get)?

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to the changes [here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/releases?page=3).
Its jest official repo mentioning all the changes with various version. Check if there are any breaking changes.